# C# has no friend class - what are better options

Tags: c#, design, design-patterns, object-oriented, architecture

I return to this question every couple of years, so now i decided to solve it once and for all, by asking here.

So, the sequence:

1. I'm writing a simple application that parses Json file (configuration to 3rd party app, further named as *config*) and allows user to do some editing with it. I've picked a platform, made some basic UI, binded some buttons to NewFileCommand, OpenFileCommand, SaveFileCommand, etc.
2. Now I need to store somewhere the opened (and deserialized into a class) config, so I made a new StorageService class. It has some methods like OpenFile(), ReloadFile(), SaveFile(), etc. They are called from the ViewModel, StorageService opens file, **read the config and store it as a field**. When needed, it saves it to a file - so far so good.
3. At this moment, I want to add some manipulations with the config itself. I really dont want to put it in the StorageService. Some methods like GetConfigPropertyByNameAndDoSomeMagicWithIt() are definitely should be placed to another service.
4. So, i made another service, OperationsService. Now i want it it have an access to the config, stored in StorageService and add methods GetConfigPropertyByNameAndDoSomeMagicWithIt(). I dont want to expose the StorageService.config into the public API - because i already have all necessary accessors. For everyone else, except of OperationsService. Which i pretty much want to make the one, who can access StorageService.config. Looking like a good use case for old good C++ concept of the "friend" class, where OperationsService can be declared as a friend of StorageService and access its internals.
5. I'm recalling that I've faced similar issue earlier, so I googled for "C# friendly class", opened [the first link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204739/what-is-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-friend) in a hope to find a modern solution - and realized that I've a deja vu feeling.

So, what is a flow in my current approach? How to solve it in "proper modern OOP architecture" manner?
Make OperationsService an internal class of StorageService? That would mean that all the code would be stored in the same file (pretty much violation of SOLID).
Make OperationsService an internal class of StorageService and make it partial and move to another file? Seems kinda creepy.

In general, I don't even want OperationsService to be exposed (not even to register it in IoC container) for the rest of the app - just to do the heavy lifting. OperationsService would be not that large, so I don't want to make a third (some kind of a wrapper service) as well.

In terms of objects I can rephrase the problem as "object A has a private field, which should be accessible only for object B. Object's A responsibility is IO, Object's B responsibility is some logic, so they cant be merged".

To sum up, we have:

- config, which is POCO and contains deserialized data from Json.
- StorageService, which contains OpenFile(), SaveFile(). Also, it contains current instance of the config.
- theoretical OperationsService, which contains some logic in GetConfigPropertyByNameAndDoSomeMagicWithIt(). In order to run that logic, it has to have an access to the config as well. The question is how to relate OperationsService and StorageService.

Comment: The SOLID principles say nothing about physical distribution of code to files.

Comment: What is a "C# friendly class?"

Comment: @DocBrown Well, i've been always referring S to be related to it: "single reason to change" kinda leads to that (at least for me). Kinda: if more than one class in a file - then more then one reason to change it. But technically you're right: its not about the physical disctribution.

Comment: @RobertHarvey "friendly class: is a concept that exists in C++, but not in C#. You can allow another class to have an access to internals of the first class. I'll add a clarification to the post.

Comment: That is a *friend* class, not a "friendly" class.  The moral equivalent in C# is probably a *partial* class.

Comment: Overall, I think you're vastly overthinking this.  If I understand your problem correctly, it is completely solved by using the Newtonsoft.JSON library.  No need for StorageThis, ControllerThat, or any friend classes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/204744

Comment: @RobertHarvey Oh, cmon, you could have said that without asking about "friendly" :) Anyway, I'm not really sure its a good replacement (maybe mentally) because "friend class" means "1 of 2 different classes has an access to another one".

Comment: I didn't know what you meant by "friendly."  Have a look at Newtonsoft.JSON before you do anything else.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Dont get too deep into the details. Yes, most of things are solved by Newtonsoft, but think of some custom logic that i need to store not in the StorageService.

Comment: What sort of custom logic?

Comment: What's wrong with making a class that's explicitly and openly in charge of reading, storing, and editing the config? No need for 'friend' classes.

Comment: @EricKing: Newtonsoft.JSON already does all of that anyway.

Comment: @RobertHarvey yep

Comment: @RobertHarvey Config contains several fields and 2 lists. At some moment, i need to do a search through one of the lists, do some comparison to another list and some of the fields. Newtonsoft.JSON is doing a great job on serialization\deserialization, but my question is about where to store all that logic, that is not related to save\load.

Comment: In a new class.  Call it anything you like.  `public class SearchAndCompareJson`.  Hand the two JSON objects to the constructor.  Or simply add that logic to the code in the same class where you're performing the deserialization.

Comment: You don't need some overblown architecture to do this.  You just need to write some sensible object-oriented code.  And you certainly don't need any "friend" classes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I've definitely checked that answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/204744 ) before and i definitely dont want to do some hacks. I'm looking for a clear solution from the point of OOP logic. "You're overcomplicating things, better to do it X way" is a good one. "Make a wrapper service, hide existing StorageService and OperationsService inside of it" is another good one, but i dont really like it. Thats why i'm asking this question.

Comment: What is the name of your class where you're deserializing your two JSON objects?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I already have almost all necessary code (except some more logical editing methods) - now i need a place to put it in.

Comment: What is the name of your class where you're deserializing your two JSON objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81355/discussion-between-vitalii-vasylenko-and-robert-harvey).

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko How about it friend? Pun intended : ) I'd sure love your take on my proposed answer below, from yesterday -- is it not the appropriate OOP pattern you were looking for in order to solve this case? Not involving either the use of `internal` or even nesting a class as you have yourself said it somewhat bothers you from a SOLID perspective.

Comment: @SkepticalEmpiricist I really like your idea, playing with it atm :) Seems the closest case out of all options.

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko Great to hear. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I'm having problem seeing where the real problem is. Maybe make a diagram showing various classes and what dependencies you don't want to create? I don't know what design problem you have. To me, this is question about dependencies and what piece of code should know about what other piece of code.

Comment: @Euphoric I've added EDIT2 with some brief sum-up.

Comment: Why do you think this can be solved by "friend" class and not by greatly changing the design and responsibilities of the classes? Why can't you make the config public? Sorry if this was already answered. Too much stuff to find exact answer.

Comment: @Euphoric No worries. I see the problem is in "placing logic and io into services". By the naive thinking, i'd put the logic into StorageService. But that would violate single-responsibility, and it just looks ugly, when a single class has some io-related things and some logic. The "friend" option sounds like a solution in this case: StorageService remains as the main entry point towards the config, and a "friendly" OperatinonsService (as a small addon to the StorageService) just contain some extra logic.

Comment: @Euphoric And i'm pretty much opened to any discussion and options: making a config public is pretty much an option. I just dont want to do that without a strong reason, because i already have all necessary accessors in StorageService. I just need to add a bit of logic, but i'm not sure where exactly. And i feel i'm returning to the same question once in a while, in different projects, so i decided to start this discussion.

Comment: The closest C#/.NET has to Friend class is the InternalsVisibleTo attribute, which gives an external assembly access to the internals of the assembly that declares it.

Comment: Friend declarations in C# are sorely missed and, as has been shown multiple times, there is no nice workaround, only ugly hacks, chief among them making private members public.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of priveliging `OperationsService` over the rest of the system in regards to specific data is directly passing such data to it on a need to use basis: You could keep your config manipulation logic inside `OperationsService` and add a public `AcceptOperations()` method in `StorageService` that takes an `OperationsService` object as an arg and calls upon its relevant config manipulation logic, directly passing to it any privately held relevant config data.

Concretely, you could still have `GetConfigPropertyByNameAndDoSomeMagicWithIt()` be a member of `OperationsService`, that would call `AcceptOperations()` on the relevant `StorageService` instance and pass `this` as an arg. `AcceptOperations()` itself would call some concrete `ManipulateConfig()` method on the `OperationsService` instance given to it as a param, passing the internal config data to be manipulated as args for `ManipulateConfig()`.

This proposal takes in part some resemblance to the classic OOP [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern), excluding the *Double Dispatch* idiom but keeping the concept of restrictively defining who can visit what and definitely in keeping with the original idea behind the pattern which is to perform such separation of responsibilities such that *"... [it provides] the ability to add new operations to existent object structures without modifying the structures."* The whole idea of such a pattern is to aid follow the [Open-closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle) which is one of SOLID principles, keeping of which you have mentioned to be a concern of yours to begin with.

Comment: This one is seems to be the most suitable approach in my case. The Visitor patters is exactly what i've been looking for.

Answer (score 6):

You can put the classes you want to be friendly with one another in a separate assembly. Then only declare the ones you want to be available from outside the assembly as **public**. The ones you want to hide from classes in other assemblies you declare **internal**. This should give you pretty much what you want.

From an OOP perspective this is better than friend since friend allows access beyond public members, which is inherently contra-OOP.

Comment: I got your point. Though, i'm not really up for having multiple assemblies just because of that :)  

Basically, i have a small StorageService, who can read and deserialize (pure IO) class, and it stores the result (so i can serialize and write it later). What i need is to expand that and add some logic (somewhere).

Comment: Just some thoughts loud:
The part *stores the result of reading* might be the key. Basically, if i store the result in just another service (CacheService?) and keep StorageService stateless - in that case i dont need OperationsService to have a privileged access to StorageService.

Comment: Access-Control is not inherently a part of OOP, though it is a common feature.

Comment: In terms of objects i can rephrase the problem as "object A has a private field, which should be accessible only for object B. Object's A responsibility is IO, Object's B responsibility is some logic, so they cant be merged".

Comment: OK, here's another approach. You can put your friend class within the class that is to use it, as a member, and declare it private (make it a **nested class**). I think this only works one way (the containing class can use the contained class) but that is probably OK.

Comment: @MartinMaat Yep, that's a good option. The only downside is that i'll have the Storage and Operations in the same file. Probably its not that big issue. Or i can make nested class partial and move Operations to another file - not sure how good this as an option though

Comment: @VitaliiVasylenko `object A has a private field, which should be accessible only for object B` Your definition of "private" is not C#'s definition of private. "An external class needs access to this private field" is a contradiction. If it needs external access, then it is not private. If it is private, then no one but its owner has access to it. Even if you could, it makes little sense for a  private field to be hidden from a _subtype_ of the class, but not a declared friend. Friend classes violate core OOP principles and therefore do not exist in C#.

Comment: @Flater I see your point, but try not to think too hard in terms of definition. Check the accepted answer - the Visitor pattern is doing exactly what i was looking for: field is private in object A, yet it is accessible for object B.

Comment: @Flater "Friend classes violate core OOP principles". Then OOP principles are wrong and need to be discarded.

Comment: @kaalus: You say OOP is wrong, I say friend classes are wrong. That's just the opposite conclusion drawn from the same conflicting situation. However, C# clearly favors OOP over friend classes; so our opinions don't really matter when discussing how C# works and expects you to write code. As mentioned in this answer: _"From an OOP perspective this is better than friend since friend allows access beyond public members, which is inherently contra-OOP."_ C# is written from this perspective, and that's not a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Objects are supposed to handle their internal state and should be modifying themselves as necessary. I think you've extracted you objects incorrectly. `Storage Service` is really a persistence manager and it shouldn't be holding config values as internal values. Storage service should just manage the translation from file to object and vice versa. then you could either have a config object that has all the methods that do stuff to config values or expose them, or a config manager class that accepts a config object on creation and exposes the necessary access methods.

The reason you are having trouble is that `Storage Service` is currently breaking the single responsibility principle. It becomes more apparent when you are attempting to break it further with `GetConfigPropertyByNameAndDoSomeMagicWithIt()`. The proper solution in such a case would be to refactor to objects with better defined responsibilities. friend is a band-aid solution to a poor design.

Comment: Sorry but I have to disagree with you regarding "friend is a band-aid solution to a poor design." In the context of C++, it is a mainline and longstanding language feature. Specifically, there is enough basis to surmise that `friend` does not at all violate encapsulation. As such, I find it hard to accept plainly such a claim that it is a *band-aid solution*. Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17434/when-should-you-use-friend-in-c/ and mainly here in this well respected and authoritative resource: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/friends#friends-and-encap

Comment: If i have config object that has all the methods to do stuff - that will break config's single responsibility (its just a POCO object, only stores the data). But i agree with point that StorageService has a state (the config itself) - i assumed that it might be the weak point. But if i follow your advice - that would make config data public. I want to keep it private, but available for OperationsService - and how exactly to do that is actually the core of my question.

Comment: "Objects are supposed to handle their internal state and should be modifying themselves as necessary" This is fine until you encounter a (common) situation where you have two classes that work in tandem to handle their shared state.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're missing is IConfigurationService a concrete version of which depends on IConfigStorageService. You could have LocalConfigStorageService, which picks up config from a file...or S3ConfigStorageService which retrieves from a cloud bucket. Or even DatabaseConfigStorageService which picks it up from a database. In all three cases the IConfigStorageService is responsible for retrieving a config and storing the update to the config for the IConfigurationService.

The IConfigurationService uses the returned config to respond to the consumers requests of it.

This specifically is an instance of the [Bridge Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_pattern)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It absolutely makes sense for a bit larger apps. If\when app will grow, i'd definitely go that way - but for now its a bit early and unnecessary, because as of this moment, config comes only from the file and there are no plans to add DB or cloud. Good point, but, main question "where to store logic" is still unanswered :)